# jQuery regex to allow rather a number or nothing before decimal place

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, numbers, decimal

So I'm working on some Regex which will allow the user to enter a number or a decimal number.
So far I have this:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Which allows the user to enter any of these samples:

```
10
0.50
1000
20.30
```

However, I want to user to not have to put a leading zero before the decimal place.  So I need the user to be allowed to enter:

```
.10
.40
.67
```

As well as all the other samples I showed above. 
I know its probably going to be a simple change, but I can't seem to find it myself.  Can anyone help?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: so you don't want to match `0.50`. am i correct?

Comment: No I did want to match that, along with .50
But "lpg" has helped me out and I've sorted it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Comment: This will allow empty string also.

Comment: Cheers,  Works great :)

Comment: anubhava is right, but I think that if you can assure the string is not empty, this is the simplest solution...

Comment: The string being empty is ok as the system defaults to zero if its empty (Which is valid for what I'm doing).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex alternation:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uI2dD3/1)